# chown won't change ownership

Tags: linux, chown

I've created a directory as root, but when I try to change ownership if it, it won't change! I have no idea why. (I've snipped the results of `ls -halg` for brevity, in case you're wondering why some files are missing...)

```
root@localhost:/opt/tomcat/conf# mkdir Catalina
root@localhost:/opt/tomcat/conf# ls -halg
total 244K
drwxr-x--- 3 tomcat 4.0K May 12 17:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 tomcat 4.0K May 10 02:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   4.0K May 12 17:09 Catalina
-rw-r----- 1 tomcat  13K May 12 15:32 catalina.policy
-rw-r----- 1 tomcat 7.1K Mar 30 10:29 catalina.properties
root@localhost:/opt/tomcat/conf# chown tomcat Catalina
root@localhost:/opt/tomcat/conf# ls -halg
total 244K
drwxr-x--- 3 tomcat 4.0K May 12 17:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 tomcat 4.0K May 10 02:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   4.0K May 12 17:09 Catalina
-rw-r----- 1 tomcat  13K May 12 15:32 catalina.policy
-rw-r----- 1 tomcat 7.1K Mar 30 10:29 catalina.properties
root@localhost:/opt/tomcat/conf#
```

When I made the tomcat directory yesterday, it was happy to `chown -R /opt/tomcat` everything to the tomcat user like it should. I'm really at a loss at why such a simple command fails.

Comment: You change the *user* but your command displays only the *group*. Just try again with a simple `ls -l`.

Comment: You can also verify with: `stat Catalina`. @A.B feel free to submit that as an answer.

Comment: Use this command ls -lrt and share the output with us.

Comment: Sorry, I had some things come up and this sort of sat in the background for a while - @A.B 's suggestion did show properly - if that was an answer instead of a comment it would have a checkmark by now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand:

`chown` with a simple *user* parameter, not including the separator `:` (or obsolete `.`) changes the *user* ownership of further given file(s) and leaves the *group* ownership of the file(s) unchanged.

On the other hand:

`ls -halg` displays only the *group* ownership of a file in its output because of the included option `-g`.

Thus changing only the *user*, which worked (no error was displayed) didn't change the result of `ls -halg`. `ls -hal` should have been used here to see the change.